# need to convert sql server query to mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, group-by

I've need to convert following sql server query into mysql

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, p_date)) [date],
       SUM(p_amount) [sum]
FROM tbl_Payments
WHERE DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, p_date)) BETWEEN '20130701' AND '20130731'
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, p_date))
```

column names: p_date,p_amount

Comment: What is the issue that you are having when try this yourself?

Comment: though it doesn't look like a difficult query to convert, what do you have so far?

Comment: @Funkotron_King how should we specify zero for date in mysql

Comment: @ratheeshZachariah Why do you want 0 for a date? if there has been no payment (or it is pending) the result should be null. Is there another reason you need 0?

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks correct except few things like

1. Replace `[]` with backticks "`" for escaping
2. DATE and TIME function syntax are different in MySQL than SQL Server. For more information on MySQL DATE and TIME functions see [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)
3. Try using a minimum date like `1-1-1` instead of `0`

   `select DATEDIFF('1-1-1', now())`

   `select DATE_ADD('1-1-1', interval DATEDIFF(now(), '1-1-1') day);`

With all this the below query should work fine in MySQL

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('1-1-1', interval DATEDIFF(p_date, '1-1-1') day) `date`,
         SUM(p_amount) `sum`
         FROM tbl_Payments
         WHERE DATE_ADD('1-1-1', interval DATEDIFF(p_date, '1-1-1') day)
         BETWEEN '20130701' AND '20130731'
        GROUP BY DATE_ADD('1-1-1', interval DATEDIFF(p_date, '1-1-1') day)
```